# How to format columns using awk?

Tags: linux, awk, text-formatting

The file rectData.ssv contains:

```
rectangle1;1;2
rectangle2;1;10
rect4;10;10
```

How could the following command be changed to align the columns:

```
$ awk -F ";" '{ print "area of", $1,":", $2 * $3}' rectData.ssv
area of rectangle1 : 2
area of rectangle2 : 10
area of rect4 : 100
```

Expected output as follows:

```
area of rectangle1:   2
area of rectangle2:   10
area of rect4:        100
```

(2, 10 and 100 are left aligned)

OR:

```
area of rectangle1:    2
area of rectangle2:   10
area of rect4:       100
```

(2, 10 and 100 are right aligned)

---

Also, how can a line be added at the end with a total (2, 10, 100 and 112 are right aligned):

```
area of rectangle1:    2
area of rectangle2:   10
area of rect4:       100
TOTAL AREA:          112
```

Comment: What have _you_ tried? Have you considered `printf`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this looks very much like a "do my homework for me" question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this adaption of your attempt:

```
$ awk -F ";" '
        {TOT += $2 * $3
         printf "area of %s: %*d\n", $1, 14-length($1), $2 * $3
        }
END     {printf "TOTAL AREA: %*d\n", 12, TOT
        }
' file
area of rectangle1:    2
area of rectangle2:   10
area of rect4:       100
TOTAL AREA:          112
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F ';' -v OFS='\t' '
    { tot+=prod=$2*$3; print "area of " $1 ":", prod }
    END { print "TOTAL AREA:", tot+0 }
' file | column -s$'\t' -t
area of rectangle1:  2
area of rectangle2:  10
area of rect4:       100
TOTAL AREA:          112
```